# Upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 on on Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, bash, upgrade, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on Windows 10 as **Bash on Ubuntu for Windows 10**. I am trying to upgrade it using:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

First, it gives this output:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [836 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1265 kB]
Fetched 1266 kB in 9s (129 kB/s)
authenticate 'xenial.tar.gz' against 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'xenial.tar.gz'
```

Then quickly all the text disappears from the terminal and it says:

```
[screen is terminating]
```

Please let me know how can I update Ubuntu on Bash on Ubuntu for Windows 10 from the terminal.

Comment: you can't upgrade because Windows does not allow you to do that, if you want the lastest Ubuntu LST release upgrade Windows 10 to Creators Update (1703)

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/upgrade-bash-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: @RenatoA. Please add that as an answer. :)